# Django unit test to verify None fields on model

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-testing

I was wondering how to unit test None fields on a model?

Imagine the following model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(user)
    date = DateField(blank=False, null= False)
```

And the test class:

```
class ItemCreationTest(TestCase):
    def test_item_without_date(self):
        item = Item()
        # test should fail...
```

Since I do not provide a date the test should fail. However, the test succeeds... What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to save object to DB and test will fail:

```
item = Item()
item.save()
```

Or shorter version with the same result:

```
Item.objects.create()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
class ItemCreationTest(TestCase):
def test_item_without_date(self):
    item = Item()
    item.save()
```